# How to implement CancellationToken support in DropNet?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, restsharp, cancellation, dropnet

I want to asynchronously access DropBox API in a MonoTouch app.
I thought it would be convenient to use [DropNet](https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet/) which itself relies on [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/).

Both libraries work well but DropNet overloads that return `Task`s don't give you a way to associate requests with cancellation tokens.

This is how their implementation looks:

```
public Task<IRestResponse> GetThumbnailTask(string path, ThumbnailSize size)
{
    if (!path.StartsWith("/")) path = "/" + path;
    var request = _requestHelper.CreateThumbnailRequest(path, size, Root);
    return ExecuteTask(ApiType.Content, request, cancel);
}
```

`ExecuteTask` implementation is based on `TaskCompletionSource` and [was](https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet/blob/master/DropNet/Extensions/RestClientExtensions.cs) originally [written by Laurent Kempé](http://www.laurentkempe.com/post/Extending-existing-NET-API-to-support-asynchronous-operations.aspx):

```
public static class RestClientExtensions
{
    public static Task<TResult> ExecuteTask<TResult>(
        this IRestClient client, IRestRequest request
        ) where TResult : new()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();

        WaitCallback asyncWork = _ => {
            try {
                client.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(request,
                    (response, asynchandle) => {
                        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                            tcs.SetException(new DropboxException(response));
                        } else {
                            tcs.SetResult(response.Data);
                        }
                    }
                );
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                    tcs.SetException(exc);
            }
        };

        return ExecuteTask(asyncWork, tcs);
    }


    public static Task<IRestResponse> ExecuteTask(
        this IRestClient client, IRestRequest request
        )
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();

        WaitCallback asyncWork = _ => {
            try {
                client.ExecuteAsync(request,
                    (response, asynchandle) => {
                        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                            tcs.SetException(new DropboxException(response));
                        } else {
                            tcs.SetResult(response);
                        }
                    }
                );
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                    tcs.SetException(exc);
            }
        };

        return ExecuteTask(asyncWork, tcs);
   }

    private static Task<TResult> ExecuteTask<TResult>(
        WaitCallback asyncWork, TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs
        )
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(asyncWork);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

How do I change or extend this code to support cancellation with `CancellationToken`?
I'd like to call it like this:

```
var task = dropbox.GetThumbnailTask(
    "/test.jpg", ThumbnailSize.ExtraLarge2, _token
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `CancellationToken` is a value type, we can add it as an optional parameter to the APIs with default value and avoid null checks, which is sweet.

```
public Task<IRestResponse> GetThumbnailTask(
    string path, ThumbnailSize size, CancellationToken cancel = default(CancellationToken)
) {
    if (!path.StartsWith("/")) path = "/" + path;
    var request = _requestHelper.CreateThumbnailRequest(path, size, Root);
    return ExecuteTask(ApiType.Content, request, cancel);
}
```

Now, RestSharp `ExecuteAsync` method returns `RestRequestAsyncHandle` that encapsulates underlying `HttpWebRequest`, along with `Abort` method. This is how we cancel things.

```
public static Task<TResult> ExecuteTask<TResult>(
    this IRestClient client, IRestRequest request, CancellationToken cancel = default(CancellationToken)
    ) where TResult : new()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
    try {
        var async = client.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(request, (response, _) => {
            if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested || response == null)
                return;

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                tcs.TrySetException(new DropboxException(response));
            } else {
                tcs.TrySetResult(response.Data);
            }
        });

        cancel.Register(() => {
            async.Abort();
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        tcs.TrySetException(ex);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}

public static Task<IRestResponse> ExecuteTask(this IRestClient client, IRestRequest request, CancellationToken cancel = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
    try {
        var async = client.ExecuteAsync<IRestResponse>(request, (response, _) => {
            if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested || response == null)
                return;

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                tcs.TrySetException(new DropboxException(response));
            } else {
                tcs.TrySetResult(response);
            }
        });

        cancel.Register(() => {
            async.Abort();
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        tcs.TrySetException(ex);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Finally, [Lauren's implementation](http://www.laurentkempe.com/post/Extending-existing-NET-API-to-support-asynchronous-operations.aspx) puts requests in thread pool but I don't see a reason to do so—`ExecuteAsync` is asynchronous itself. So I don't do that.

And that's it for cancelling DropNet operations.

I also made a few tweaks which may be useful to you.

Because I had no way of scheduling DropBox `Task`s without resorting to wrapping `ExecuteTask` calls into another `Task`s, I decided to find an optimal concurrency level for requests, which turned out to be `4` for me, and set it explicitly:

```
static readonly Uri DropboxContentHost = new Uri("https://api-content.dropbox.com");

static DropboxService()
{
    var point = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(DropboxContentHost);
    point.ConnectionLimit = 4;
}
```

I was also content with letting unhandled task exceptions rot in hell, so that's what I did:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, e) => {
    e.SetObserved();
};
```

One last observation is you **shouldn't call `Start()` on a task returned by `DropNet`** because the task starts right away. If you don't like that, you'll need to wrap `ExecuteTask` in yet another “real” task not backed by `TaskCompletionSource`.